# SQL cannot ORDER BY before JOIN CTE. Alternatives?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012, VS2015, SSMS 2017

I have a query that is currently using an `OUTER APPLY` that is slowing down the query. I know that I could speed it up by changing the `OUTER APPLY` into a `LEFT JOIN ON` clause, but the `OUTER APPLY` uses `ORDER BY` to sort the table. `JOIN` will not let me use `ORDER BY`. Is there a work-around for this?

Current query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.ItemID,
    ISNULL(DATEDIFF(s, t1.localTimeStamp, t3.localTimeStamp),
    DATEDIFF(s, t1.localTimeStamp, @End)) AS Duration, 
    t1.localTimeStamp AS TimeStamp
FROM 
    CTE1 AS t1
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP 1 localTimeStamp
     FROM CTE1 AS t2
     WHERE t2.localTimeStamp > t1.localTimeStamp AND t2.ItemID = t1.ItemID
     ORDER BY t2.localTimeStamp ASC) AS t3
```

This query essentially takes an item and calculates the duration in between entries of the table for individual items. The source table is CTE1 which contains rows with multiple ItemIDs, Values, and localTimeStamps that are in no particular order. I could not use `ORDER BY` in the `WITH CTE` clause either.

New query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.Value, t1.tName, t1.ItemID, 
    ISNULL(DATEDIFF(s, t1.localTimeStamp, t2.localTimeStamp),
    DATEDIFF(s, t1.localTimeStamp, @End)) AS Duration, 
    t1.localTimeStamp AS TimeStamp
FROM 
    CTE1 t1
LEFT JOIN 
    CTE1 t2 ON t2.localTimeStamp > t1.localTimeStamp AND t2.ItemID = t1.ItemID
```

The problem is that it will take ALL the rows with greater timestamps not just the one that is next (by order of localTimeStamp not actual row number).

Can I get a Join to work or is there another way to do this that does not slow down the query?

(I know that the join is faster because even though I am joining significantly more rows this second query still beats the first one.)

Since I am sure this will get flagged as a duplicate question I want to point out that i have read many other similar questions on this site about this and every one that asks to order a join clause is joining on column1 = column2, where order does not matter they were simply mistaken. since I am joining on column1 > column2 the order does indeed matter. perhaps the solution is I should use outer apply, but this question has NOT been asked here before.

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: This looks like something the `LEAD()` window function was built for, unless I'm misunderstanding something... e.g. `LEAD(localtimestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY localtimestamp)`? You wouldn't need a join if you use `LEAD()`

Comment: Well, the `OUTER APPLY` isn't exactly what's slowing down the query, it's almost certainly that there's no index to support the `ORDER BY`, that you're reading the underlying table twice, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `lead()`?

```
SELECT tt.ItemID,
       COALESCE(DATEDIFF(second, t.localTimeStamp, LEAD(t.localTimeStamp) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ItemId ORDER BY t.localTimeStamp)),
                DATEDIFF(second, t.localTimeStamp, @End)
               ) as Duration, 
       t.localTimeStamp as TimeStamp
FROM CTE1 t;
```

Microsoft has done a good job optimizing `APPLY`.  I would guess that the performance problem is running the CTE twice, which the `lead()` should fix.

Comment: you are missing a close parenthesis after the `OVER ()` statement. but your answer was indeed correct. with your solution the query ran in 5 seconds. with my outer apply it ran in 72 seconds. I have never used a `LEAD()` statement before.

Answer (score 0):

Change your second query to use

Min(t2.localtimestamp) 
and group by the rest of the columns

Comment: I do not understand how to apply your answer.